# Sharing code between iOS Project and custom created iOS Framework

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios-frameworks

I have written a framework that make use of [SAMKeychain](https://github.com/soffes/SAMKeychain). This frameworkA is used inside the an iOS project.

The iOS project in return has some additional classes that uses the same [SAMKeychain](https://github.com/soffes/SAMKeychain). I am trying to find a way to refer the SAMKeychain in the framework and include as a dependency(But do not include SAMKeychain sources) inside the framework.

I tried referencing just the header files of SAMKeychain in the framework and try to build the framework but It failed with linking error **_OBJC_CLASS_$_SAMKeychain**

What is the best way to share third party code between the framework and iOS project

Comment: Cocoapods is the best solution if I understand your question properly.

Comment: How? :) I have used cocoapods inside my framework for SAMKeychain. But   If I do the same for iOS project It would result in duplicate symbols...

Comment: If both `Pods` and Your App using the same `Pod` `Cocoapods` should resolve that dependency.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to use dynamic frameworks . So when frameworkA is made it should be dynamic and the Pods it contains that is SAMKeychain should also be dynamic to do that you use

`use_frameworks!` in Podfile which will create SAMkeychain.framework for the Pod SAMkeychain.

After the frameworkA binary is created in the iOS project you have to add both frameworkA and SAMKeychain.framework as embedded binaries. And this will work just ok.

Note that if you don't use use_frameworks in the Podfile it would generate a static library of the pod which will be included in the binary of frameworkA.

Hope this helps someone!